Scroll Position Retention Issue in Reverse Infinite Scroll for Chat Messages
I am implementing a chat application but having problem in rendering history of chat. user can scroll down so that new messages are loaded on top using react-infinite-scroll-component. After a new batch of messages is loaded via an API call in a reverse infinite scroll setup, the scroll position resets to the top of the newly loaded messages rather than staying at the point where it was left off. This causes the application to trigger next API call quickly , also user misses all the old messages in the API call.
Here is the implementation
export default function RenderGroupMessages({
  messages,
  loadMore,
  hasMore,
  groupDetails,
  isLoadingMoreMessages,
  isNewMessage,
  setIsNewMessage,
  setSelectedMessage,
  setIsReplying,
  currentUserId,
}: {
  messages: any;
  loadMore: () => Promise<void>;
  hasMore: boolean;
  groupDetails: any;
  isLoadingMoreMessages: boolean;
  isNewMessage: boolean;
  setIsNewMessage: (value: boolean) => void;
  setSelectedMessage: any;
  setIsReplying: (value: boolean) => void;
  currentUserId: string;
}) {
  const initialized = useRef(false);

  // to scroll down to the beginning of the chat
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!initialized.current) {
      if (messages?.length > 0) {
        initialized.current = true;
      }

      if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById("scrollableDiv") as HTMLDivElement | null;
        if (scrollableDiv) {
          scrollableDiv.scrollTop = scrollableDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
      }
    }
  }, [messages]);

  // to scroll down to the beginning of the chat when a new message is received
  useEffect(() => {
    if (messages?.length > 0 && isNewMessage) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById("scrollableDiv") as HTMLDivElement | null;
        if (scrollableDiv) {
          scrollableDiv.scrollTop = scrollableDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
        setIsNewMessage(false);
      }, 0);
    }
  }, [messages]);

  return (
    <div id="scrollableDiv" className="no-scrollbar max-h-full max-w-full overflow-y-auto">
      {isLoadingMoreMessages ? (
        <div className="my-6 grid place-content-center">
          <CircularSpinner size="w-8 h-8" />
        </div>
      ) : null}
      <InfiniteScroll
        className="px-6"
        dataLength={messages?.length}
        next={() => {}}
        hasMore={hasMore}
        inverse={true} // Set inverse to true to reverse the scroll direction
        scrollableTarget="scrollableDiv" // Provide a unique target ID to control scrolling
        loader={<></>}
        endMessage={<></>}
        onScroll={async (e: any) => {
          if (e.target.scrollTop === 0 && hasMore) {
            const scrollableDiv = document.getElementById("scrollableDiv") as HTMLDivElement | null;
            if (scrollableDiv) {
              const previousHeight = scrollableDiv.scrollHeight;
              await loadMore();
              scrollableDiv.scrollTop = scrollableDiv.scrollHeight - previousHeight;
            }
          }
        }}
      >
 </div>
  );
}


this is container where I used above component.
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import RenderGroupMessages from './RenderGroupMessages' 
import { apiConnector } from './apiConnector' 

interface GroupMessageRendererProps {
  groupId: string;
  token: string;
  userId: string;
}

const GroupMessageRenderer: React.FC<GroupMessageRendererProps> = ({ groupId, token, userId }) => {
  const [receivedMessages, setReceivedMessages] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [sentMessages, setSentMessages] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [sentMessagesProcessing, setSentMessagesProcessing] = useState<any[]>([]);
  const [lastMessageId, setLastMessageId] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [hasMoreMessages, setHasMoreMessages] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [groupDetails, setGroupDetails] = useState<any>(null);
  const [isLoadingMoreMessages, setIsLoadingMoreMessages] = useState(false);
  const [isNewMessage, setIsNewMessage] = useState(false);
  const [selectedMessage, setSelectedMessage] = useState<any>(null);
  const [isReplying, setIsReplying] = useState(false);

  const receivedMessagesRef = useRef(receivedMessages);
  const sentMessagesRef = useRef(sentMessages);

  useEffect(() => {
    receivedMessagesRef.current = receivedMessages;
    sentMessagesRef.current = sentMessages;
  }, [receivedMessages, sentMessages]);

  const extractData = useMemo(() => {
    const arr = [
      ...receivedMessages,
      ...sentMessages,
      ...sentMessagesProcessing,
    ].sort((a, b) => new Date(a.timestamp).valueOf() - new Date(b.timestamp).valueOf());

    const byDay: Record<string, any[]> = {};
    arr.forEach((message) => {
      const date = message.timestamp.split("T")[0];
      byDay[date] = byDay[date] || [];
      byDay[date].push(message);
    });

    return Object.entries(byDay);
  }, [receivedMessages, sentMessages, sentMessagesProcessing]);

  const fetchMoreMessages = async () => {
    if (isLoadingMoreMessages) return;

    setIsLoadingMoreMessages(true);
    try {
      let uri = `/userChats/get-group-chats?groupId=${groupId}&lastMessageId=${lastMessageId}`;
      const response = await apiConnector("GET", uri, {}, {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      });

      const { receivedMessages: newReceivedMessages, sentMessages: newSentMessages, lastMessageId: newLastMessageId, hasMoreMessages: newHasMoreMessages } = response.data.data;

      receivedMessagesRef.current = [...newReceivedMessages, ...receivedMessagesRef.current];
      setReceivedMessages(receivedMessagesRef.current);

      sentMessagesRef.current = [...newSentMessages, ...sentMessagesRef.current];
      setSentMessages(sentMessagesRef.current);

      setLastMessageId(newLastMessageId);
      setHasMoreMessages(newHasMoreMessages);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching messages:", error);
    } finally {
      setIsLoadingMoreMessages(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <RenderGroupMessages
      messages={extractData}
      loadMore={fetchMoreMessages}
      hasMore={hasMoreMessages}
      groupDetails={groupDetails}
      isLoadingMoreMessages={isLoadingMoreMessages}
      isNewMessage={isNewMessage}
      setIsNewMessage={setIsNewMessage}
      setSelectedMessage={setSelectedMessage}
      setIsReplying={setIsReplying}
      currentUserId={userId}
    />
  );
};

export default GroupMessageRenderer;

I wanted to know why there is not a contionous scroll after new messages are fetched , It doesn't start from where it left off. Instead to top of newly fetched messages , making user skip all the fetched messages , also making to fetch again quickly. Thanking in advance.

Maybe this answer could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48229905/9313676
